# Modular arithmetic and one-to-one functions

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

Let $S = \{0, 1, 2, 3, · · · , 99\}$ . For each of the following functions $f : S \rightarrow S$ , determine
whether it is one-to-one and onto, by computing its values for all $k ∈ S$:

Function 1: $$f(k) = (131k+27)\pmod{100}$$

Well at this point, I've computed the following:

$$
\begin{matrix}
f(0) = 27 \bmod 100 = 100i+27 \\ 
f(1) = 158 \bmod 100 = 100i+158 \\
\vdots  \\f(99) = 12996 \bmod \ 100 = 100i+12996
\end{matrix}
$$

However, I'm not sure where to go beyond this point and don't see any logical steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your task simpler, you can note that $$\begin{align}f(k) &= 131k+27\pmod{100}\\ &= 100k+31k+27\pmod{100}\\ &= 31k+27\pmod{100}.\end{align}$$ I have no idea why you'd be asked to explicitly calculate $100$ modular arithmetic values, but this should make it simpler. The first several, for example, are: $$f(0)=27\pmod{100}\\f(1)=58\pmod{100}\\f(2)=89\pmod{100}.$$ Those are simple enough. Next, we have $$\begin{align}f(3) &= 120\pmod{100}\\ &= 20\pmod{100}.\end{align}$$ We continue in this fashion, finding the first several values are $$27,58,89,20,51,82,13,44,75,6,37,68,99,30,...$$ and so on until the last value of $96.$ (Are you seeing the pattern?)

Still, this is far from the most efficient way to do this problem. Let's suppose that $f(k)=f(m)$ for some $k,m\in S,$ so that $$31k+27=31m+27\pmod{100}\\31k=31m\pmod{100}\\31(k-m)=0\pmod{100}$$ But that means that $31(k-m)=100j$ for some integer $j$, so $31$ divides $100j$. Since $31$ is prime and does not divide $100,$ then $31$ must divide $j,$ meaning that $j=31i$ for some integer $i,$ and so $$31(k-m)=100j\\31(k-m)=3100i\\k-m=100i\\k-m=0\pmod{100}\\k=m\pmod{100}.$$ Thus, $f:S\to S$ is a one-to-one function. A one-to-one function from a finite set into itself is automatically onto, and so we're done.

Comment: I see what you've done. How would this apply for $132k + 27$ and for $ 133k + 27 $. Would it follow the same principle?

Comment: For $133k+27,$ it would not only follow the same principle, you would again find that it was one-to-one and onto. For $\frac132k+27,$ though, we would not, because $$32(k-m)=100j$$ implies that $8(k-m)=25j,$ at which point we can conclude that $8$ divides $j,$ so that $$8(k-m)=200i\\k-m=25i\\k-m=0,25,50,75\pmod{100},$$ and so $k,m$ need not be equal to have $f(k)=f(m)$ when $f(k)=132k+27\pmod{100}.$ For example, $f(0)=f(25)=27.$ Since $f:S\to S$ is not one-to-one and $S$ is finite, then $f$ is not onto.

Comment: Still, the principle is the same, and we use that a function between finite sets of the same size is one-to-one if and only if it is onto.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, where did you find $f(0) = f(25) = 27$ ?

Comment: $f(0)=27$ is easy, and $f(25)=3327=33\cdot100+27=27\pmod{100}.$ That calculation isn't really even necessary, though. That $k-m=0,25,50,75\pmod{100}$ calculation showed us that $f(k)=f(m)$ so long as $k,m$ only differed by a multiple of $25.$

Comment: Gotcha! Thanks for the help!